# assert_routing not behaving as I expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rails-routing

I have the following route:

```
namespace :admin do
  get '/' => 'agents#index'
end
```

I do a rake routes.

```
admin GET      /admin(.:format)      admin/agents#index
```

Everything looks good to me.

I want to write a route test for this particular route so I write this:

```
def test_admin_root
  assert_routing(
    { :method => :get, :path => "/admin" },
    { :controller => "admin/agents", :action => "index" })
end
```

But to my surprise this doesn't seem to do the trick. I get the following error:

```
 FAIL (0:00:00.362) admin root
      The generated path <"/admin/agents"> did not match <"/admin">.
      <"/admin"> expected but was
      <"/admin/agents">.
```

I've been writing tests for all the routes so that I can start cleaning them a bit without being afraid I'm breaking something. Everything else seems to be working fine except this particular route test. Any idea what I'm doing wrong or why  we see this behavior? I'm really curious about this. Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you do `:controller => "agents"`  instead?

Comment: The controller is nested under ```/admin``` but if I try that I get this failuer:           ```The recognized options <{"controller"=>"admin/agents", "action"=>"index"}> did not match <{"controller"=>"agents", "action"=>"index"}>, difference: <{"controller"=>"agents"}>.
          <{"controller"=>"agents", "action"=>"index"}> expected but was
          <{"controller"=>"admin/agents", "action"=>"index"}>```